# A map that is injective but not a homemorphism onto its image

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

How I have to show that the map $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$\sigma(t)=(\frac{t}{1+t^4},\frac{t}{1+t^2})$ is injective but not an homeomorphism onto its image?

Comment: You should be able to prove that the image $\Gamma$ of $\sigma$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ (you should begin by drawing it using any CAS). Since $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, you can conclude that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Gamma$ are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1. In $\mathbb R$ the set $\mathbb Z$ \  $\{0\}$ is closed but in the image space $S=\{\sigma (t):t\in \mathbb R\}$ the set  $\{\sigma (n): n\in \mathbb Z$ \ $\{0\}\}$ is not closed. The point $(0,0)=\sigma (0)$ is in its closure.

Method 2. $S$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. For if $U$ is a connected open subset of $\mathbb R$ then  $\partial U$ contains at most $2$ points. But $S$ \ $\{\sigma (t): 1\leq t\leq 2 \lor -2\leq t\leq -1\}$ is connected and open in $S$ and has $4$ boundary points.

Remark: Observe that $S$ is homeomorphic to the shape of the numeral $8.$

Comment: In Method 1 I had typos. The set $\mathbb Z$ \ $\{0\}$  (not the set $\mathbb Z$).